# Add vertical scroll bar in flowLayoutPanel when control increases and horizontal automatically?

Tags: c#

When I add controls dynamically in flow-layout panel using C#  it goes out of the area. So I need both horizontal or vertical scroll to make them responsive. Can you suggest to me the properties, or a way how to make a dynamically added list box in flow layout panel responsive, so that when I change the size they become responsive.

Comment: Not what you are asking, I know, but I recommend you to take all the code that is equal in both the if and the else outside the if else structure. you can use the if/else for the location only. It will be more clear

Comment: check this now again and suggest me how to make it responsive too

Comment: now @Aimnox problem resolve as i added flowlayout panel now how to make it responsive

Comment: I have no idea what do you mean by responsive. And I have never work with FlowLayoutPanel.But it have an AutoScroll property, maybe its what you need

Comment: done that too autscroll property

Answer (score 7):

Just add the auto-scroll property to true like this:

```
 flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```